# How to add multiple rooms to this Firebase Swift Chat app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, channel

I am making an anonymous chat app, that requires a lot of view controllers and chat rooms. So, I was wondering how I could implement Rooms in firebase with the Security and Rules page. Also what would the code be in my chat view controller if I wanted to have multiple rooms set up.

I have already looked at the IOS Documentation in firebase but it doesn't really make total sense to me.

Here is my ChatViewController for further reference.

```
class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

// MARK: Properties
var messages = [JSQMessage]() // messages is an array to store the various instances of JSQMessage

var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!

// MARK: Firebase refs
// In case you’re wondering, creating another reference doesn’t mean you’re creating another connection. Every reference shares the same connection to the same Firebase database.
let rootRef = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)
var messageRef = Firebase()

var userIsTypingRef: Firebase! // reference that tracks whether the local user is typing
var usersTypingQuery: FQuery!  // FQuery, which is just like a Firebase reference, except that it’s ordered by an order function.

// Typing tracking related properties
private var localTyping = false // Store whether the local user is typing in a private property
var isTyping: Bool {
    get {
        return localTyping
    }
    set {
        // Using a computed property, update userIsTypingRef each time user updates this property.
        localTyping = newValue
        userIsTypingRef.setValue(newValue)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Main Chat!!"
    setupBubbles()

    // No avatars
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero

    messageRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("messages")
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.observeMessages()
    self.observeTyping()
}


override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    messageRef.removeAllObservers()
}


private func setupBubbles() {
    // JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory has methods that create the images for the chat bubbles. There’s even a category provided by JSQMessagesViewController that creates the message bubble colors used in the native Messages app.
    let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    outgoingBubbleImageView = factory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor())
    incomingBubbleImageView = factory.incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor())
}


// MARK: JSQMessagesCollectionView Datasource    
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
    messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {

    let message = messages[indexPath.item] // retrieve the message based on the NSIndexPath item.
    if message.senderId == senderId { // Check if the message was sent by the local user. If so, return the outgoing image view.
        return outgoingBubbleImageView
    } else {  // If the message was not sent by the local user, return the incoming image view.
        return incomingBubbleImageView
    }
}

// set text color based on who is sending the messages
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }


    return cell
}



// remove avatar support and close the gap where the avatars would normally get displayed.
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}


// MARK: - Create Message
// This helper method creates a new JSQMessage with a blank displayName and adds it to the data source.
func addMessage(id: String, text: String) {
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text)
    messages.append(message)
}

// SEND button pressed
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId() // Using childByAutoId(), you create a child reference with a unique key.
    // Create a dictionary to represent the message. A [String: AnyObject] works as a JSON-like object
    let messageItem = ["text": text, "senderId": senderId]

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // Save the value at the new child location.

    // Play the canonical “message sent” sound.
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

    // Complete the “send” action and reset the input toolbar to empty.
    finishSendingMessage()

}

// Observer logic
private func observeMessages () {

    // Start by creating a query that limits the synchronization to the last 25 messages.
    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(25)

    // Use the .ChildAdded event to observe for every child item that has been added, and will be added, at the messages location.
    messagesQuery.observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

        // Extract the senderId and text from snapshot.value.

        if let id = snapshot.value["senderId"] as? String, text = snapshot.value["text"] as? String {

            // Call addMessage() to add the new message to the data source.
            self.addMessage(id, text: text)

            // Inform JSQMessagesViewController that a message has been received.
            self.finishReceivingMessage()

        }

    }

}

// observer user typing object from Firebase
private func observeTyping() {
    // This method creates a reference to the URL of /typingIndicator, which is where you’ll update the typing status of the user. You don’t want this data to linger around after users have logged out, so you can delete it once the user has left using onDisconnectRemoveValue().

    let typingIndicatorRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("typingIndicator")
    userIsTypingRef = typingIndicatorRef.childByAppendingPath(senderId)
    userIsTypingRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()


    // initialize the query by retrieving all users who are typing. This is basically saying, “Hey Firebase, go to the key /typingIndicators and get me all users for whom the value is true.”
    usersTypingQuery = typingIndicatorRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(true)

    // Observe for changes using .Value; this will give you an update anytime anything changes.
    usersTypingQuery.observeEventType(FEventType.Value) { (data:FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

        // You're the only typing, don't show the indicator
        if data.childrenCount == 1 && self.isTyping {
            return
        }

        // Are there others typing?
        self.showTypingIndicator = data.childrenCount > 0
        self.scrollToBottomAnimated(true)
    }


}



// Mark: textView delegate
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)

    // If the text is not empty, the user is typing
     isTyping = textView.text != ""

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the first question: yes you can implement Rooms in firebase with the use of the Security and Rules page. you have to have a node set up with the roomMembers, besides the chat (Room) node.
Security and rules for the chat room would then be:

```
     "Chat": {
    "$room_id": {
      // the list of messages for a room can be read by any member
      ".read": "root.child('RoomMembers/'+$room_id+'/'+auth.uid).exists()",
       "$message_id": {
         // a new message can be created if it does not exist, but it
         // cannot be modified or deleted
         // any member of a room can write a new message
         ".write": "root.child('RoomMembers/'+$room_id+'/'+auth.uid).exists() && !data.exists() && newData.exists()"
       }
    }
  },
```

Security and rules for the roomMembers would be:

```
      "RoomMembers": {
    // if the list doesn't exist, anybody can create it
    // if it already exists, only users already in the list may modify it
    ".write": "!data.exists()",
    "$room_id": {
         // any member can read the list of member names
         ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || data.hasChild(auth.uid)"
     },
     // any logged in user can get a list of room names
    ".read": "auth !== null"
  },
```

I found most of this on the Firebase website: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html 
and here on StackOverflow: [Firebase Security rules for an app with multiple chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983970/firebase-security-rules-for-an-app-with-multiple-chat-rooms)

in full (just for the Chat and RoomMembers section):

```
{
"rules": {
  "Chat": {
    "$room_id": {
      // the list of messages for a room can be read by any member
      ".read": "root.child('RoomMembers/'+$room_id+'/'+auth.uid).exists()",
      //".write": true,
       "$message_id": {
         // a new message can be created if it does not exist, but it
         // cannot be modified or deleted
         // any member of a room can write a new message
         ".write": "root.child('RoomMembers/'+$room_id+'/'+auth.uid).exists() && !data.exists() && newData.exists()"
       }
    }
  },
  "RoomMembers": {
    // if the list doesn't exist, anybody can create it
    // if it already exists, only users already in the list may modify it
    ".write": "!data.exists()",
    "$room_id": {
         // any member can read the list of member names
         ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || data.hasChild(auth.uid)"
     },
     // any logged in user can get a list of room names
    ".read": "auth !== null"
   }
  }
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: So I do not have to do anything in either of my ViewControllers. @Peter de Vries

Comment: Also how would all of this code look like in one big chunk because I keep getting errors like, Bad String. @Peter de Vries

Comment: So Ignore the Second Question because I figured out how to lay it all out but when I save all of the rules and run it in Xcode. The code from the first room still carries over to the second room, should I do something else.

Comment: This question ^ could also apply to you Frank. @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: updated answer for code in one chunk. you would have to write a lot of code in the ViewControllers, as at the moment you just have the very basic JSQMessagesViewcontroller set up.

Comment: Yes this helps a bunch but the messages still show up in both chat rooms. @Peter de Vries